# What is $P \equiv Q$ called?

Tags: logic, notation

What is $P \equiv Q$ called? Is it called an equation, equivalence relation, or something else?

Comment: Yeah, but how do I refer to P ≡ Q ? Do I call it an equation or an equivalence relation?

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: Depends on the context. Sometimes it is just "congruent to" and the expression is a "congruence."

Comment: Can you tell us the context? Without a context, this question has no real answer.

Comment: In the context of logic I say "logical equivalence." In the context of the word "modulo," this is read "is equivalent modulo (operation, relation, thing)."

Comment: OP's not asking for the meaning, but a word or phrase for this class of expressions. @bananapeel22

Comment: In logic, this is sometimes written for "if and only if" and is then called a "logical equivalence."